# How to exclude certain element from checks

Tags: javascript, html-table, automation, cypress

Hey guys i have a table that consist of some rows and columns where one of the columns can be empty so i want to exclude it somehow.

Currently i am checking like this which looks like there is to much not needed writings

```
  cy.get('tr td.cdk-cell.amount.cdk-column-Amount').each(($column) => {
    expect($column).to.not.be.empty
 })

 cy.get('tr td.cdk-cell.cryptocurrency.cdk-column-BTC').each(($column) => {
  expect($column).to.not.be.empty
})
cy.get('tr td.cdk-cell.status.cdk-column-Status').each(($column) => {
  expect($column).to.not.be.empty
})
```

I cannot do the following since one of the columns always empty

```
cy.get('tbody[role="rowgroup"] tr td').each(($ele) => {
  expect($ele.text().trim().length).to.be.at.least(1)
})
```

So my question is how to ignore 1 column and check if all others have value present

Comment: Not very clear what you want - which column is to be excluded?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to exclude the Status column from the test

```js
cy.get('tbody[role="rowgroup"] tr td:not(.status)')
  .each($el => {
    expect($el.text().trim()).to.not.be.empty
  })
```

Comment: that is helpful thanks , will have a look